# Silverlight Player Blank When Changing ism file

Tags: .net, silverlight, expression-encoder

I am trying to get silverlight smooth streaming going on a site I am bilding and it works fine with the big buck bunny sample code which looks like this:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%" id="Object2">
<param name="source" value="SmoothStreamingBlackGlass.xap"/>
<param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="initparams"value='autoplay=False,muted=False,stretchmode=0,displaytimecode=False, playlist=<playList><playListItems><playListItem title="Big%20Buck%20Bunny" description="" mediaSource="Big%20Buck%20Bunny.ism/Manifest" adaptiveStreaming="True" thumbSource="Big%20Buck%20Bunny_Thumb.jpg" frameRate="24.0000384000614" ></playListItem></playListItems></playList>' />
<a href="http://go2.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://go2.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none" /></a>
</object>
<iframe style="visibility:hidden;height:0;width:0;border:0px"></iframe>
```

but if i change the code like this i only get a blank area when the page is rendered instead of the movie clip.

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%" id="Object2">
<param name="source" value="SmoothStreamingBlackGlass.xap"/>
<param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="initparams"value='autoplay=False,muted=False,stretchmode=0,displaytimecode=False, playlist=<playList><playListItems><playListItem title="Robotica_1080" description="" mediaSource="Robotica_1080.ism/Manifest" adaptiveStreaming="True" thumbSource="Robotica_1080_Thumb.jpg" frameRate="24.0000384000614" ></playListItem></playListItems></playList>' />
<a href="http://go2.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://go2.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none" /></a>
</object>
<iframe style="visibility:hidden;height:0;width:0;border:0px"></iframe>
```

Any ideas? I am using Encoder 3 to do the encoding set on microsoft smooth streaming for 720p with all the default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can go to **http://your_server_url/whatever_folder/Robotica_1080.ism/Manifest** in your browser and make sure you see the Manifest XML.

Then, try using the full/absolute URL to the Robotica_1080.ism/Manifest in your Source property. This will rule out relative path issues between the location of your player and the location of the ISM file.

Once that is done, use Fiddler2 to monitor the traffic between your silverlight player and your server to identify any further problems.

Comment: Ok so I tried an absolute url and that worked a lot better except for the fact I know get the silverlight 4001 error. Any ideas? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: the exact error: Requires output to be hosted on a web server running iis 7.0 with the smooth streaming handler installed and a silverlight 2 template that supports smooth streaming. Web Installer was used for the extensions and the other stuff is definately in place.